# How to pass parameters to thread by reference in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to pass multiple parameters to a thread. I have wrapped them into a class object. In which one variable (double array) i want pass it as reference (I am expecting the result in this variable). How does it possible?

```
class param
{
   int offset = 0;
   double[] v = null;
}
param p = new param();
p.v = new double[100]; // I want to pass this(v) variable by reference
p.offset = 50;

....
thread1.Start(p);
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Description

There are many solutions. One is, you can use `ParameterizedThreadStart` for that.

#### Sample

```
param p = new param();

// start the thread, and pass in your variable   
Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MyThreadMethod));
th.Start(p);

public void MyThreadMethod(object o)
{
    // o is your param
    param pv = (param)o;
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)

Comment: This is the best answer, but it doesn't fully answer the question.  OP asked how to pass by reference.  What isn't clear from this answer is that using `ParameterizedThreadStart`, by nature, passes by reference.  Any object modified in the thread will be modified for everyone reading that object, hence the need for locking.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just pass the `param` variable when you declare the thread:

```
static void Main()
{
  param p = new param();
  p.v = new double[100]; // I want to pass this(v) variable as reference
  p.offset = 50;
  Thread t = new Thread ( () => MyThreadMethod(p) );
  t.Start();
}

static void MyThreadMethod(param p) 
{
  //do something with p
  Console.WriteLine(p.v.Length);
  Console.WriteLine(p.offset);
}
```

Check out Joseph Albahari's free e-book on threading [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Passing_Data_to_a_Thread).

I like this approach since you don't need to deal with other objects -- just create a lambda in your Thread constructor and you're off to the races.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice. Passing the arguments like this was new to me. Seems you can pass just about anything without having to bake it into an object. Will definitely be useful for the future.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo - Thanks.  Yes, I really like this approach.  Much more straight-forward.  I thank J. Albahari for turning me on to that method.  His free e-book (linked in my answer) is always at my side when I program with threads.

Answer (score 2):

Since the thread is accessing members of `p`, `p` itself does not need to be passed by reference. Only if the thread assigned a new object to `p` with `p = new MyParams();` you would need to pass `p` as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        double[] v = null;

        //Put your values into a single object
        object o = new object[] { offset, v };

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(myMethod));
        thread1.Start(o);

    }
    public static void myMethod(object sender)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i try complete answer..

```
public class abc
{
    public string ttt { get; set; }
    public string fff { get; set; }
    public int v { get; set; }
    public double[] d { get; set; }
}

public void MyThreadMethod2(ref string str, ref double[] dd)
{
    str = "777";
    dd[2] = 9.9;
}

public void MyThreadMethod(object o)
{
    // o is your param
    abc pv = (abc)o;

    pv.v = 1;

    string sss = pv.fff; #because you can't ref pv, so ref sss 
    double[] mmm = pv.d;

    MyThreadMethod2(ref sss, ref mmm);

    pv.fff = sss; # and change pv.fff
}


abc aaaa = new abc();
aaaa.fff = "666";
aaaa.ttt = "666";
aaaa.v = 0;
aaaa.d = new double[3];
aaaa.d[0] = 1.0;
aaaa.d[1] = 1.1;
aaaa.d[2] = 1.2;
Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MyThreadMethod));
th.Start(aaaa);

THREAD_WAIT:;
            
if(aaaa.v == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show(aaaa.fff);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    goto THREAD_WAIT;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(aaaa.fff);
    MessageBox.Show(aaaa.d[2].ToString());
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).